# How to use typing.Protocol with modules?

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing, mypy

I'd like to define a protocol which could be satisfied by an object, which might be a module:

```py
from typing import Protocol

class MyType(Protocol):
    def foo(self) -> int:
        ...


class MyClass:
    def foo(self) -> int:
        return 1

# this is OK
a = MyClass()  # type: MyType

import mymodule
# mymodule.py just contains 
# def foo() -> int:
#     return 42

# but this is not.
b = mymodule  # type: MyType
# mypy complains saying
# Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type Module, variable has type "MyType")


import inspect
print(inspect.signature(a.foo))
print(inspect.signature(b.foo))
# both print: () -> int
```

gist here: https://gist.github.com/hjwp/e322c86d14ce0b11f08b27d7b17f7791

Comment: Modules aren't callable, so I don't think your question makes much sense.

Comment: There is an open Mypy issue on this: [Allow using modules as subtypes of protocols #5018](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5018)

Comment: Looks like [PEP 544: Modules as implementations of protocols](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#modules-as-implementations-of-protocols) isn't supported by `mypy` yet...

Comment: fwiw, it's now supported by `pyright` https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/1341

Answer (score 1):

I don't use mypy but I do check types in VSCode and this works for me:

```
from typing import Protocol

class MyType(Protocol):
    @staticmethod
    def foo() -> int:
        ...


import mymodule
# mymodule.py just contains 
# def foo() -> int:
#     return 42

def test(something: MyType):
    print(something.foo())  # prints 42

test(mymodule)  # type checking OK here!
```